# My object is coming up undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in JavaScript and this might seem like a total noob question but I am having an issue where my object comes up undefined.

```
const createTodoTable = new M(
  "table", // name
  "schema", // schema
  "table.sql" // SQL file
)

const mS = [{
  migrations: [createTodoTable],
  sequenceName: "init"
}]

console.log(mS);
```

When I call console.log I get the correct output, which is `[ { migrations: [ [Migration] ], sequenceName: 'init' } ]`

```
massive(dbConfig).then((db) => {
 console.log(mS);
})
```

But when I call it here I get `undefined.`

What is the reason for this?

EDIT

```
const { BaseActionWatcher } = require("demux")
const { MongoActionReader } = require("demux-eos")
const { MassiveActionHandler } = require("demux-postgres")
const { M } = require("demux-postgres")
const massive = require("massive")

const handlerVersions = [
      {
        versionName: 'v1',
        deferUntilIrreversible: true,
      },
  ]

const createTodoTable = new M(
  "table", // name
  "schema", // schema
  "table.sql" // SQL file
)

const mS = [{
  migrations: [createTodoTable],
  sequenceName: "init"
}]

console.log(mS);


const dbConfig = {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 5432,
  database: 'db',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'pass'
}

massive(dbConfig).then((db) => {
    console.log(mS);
        const actionHandler = new MassiveActionHandler(
    handlerVersions,
    db,
    dbConfig.schema,
    mS
  )
  const actionReader = new MongoActionReader({
    startAtBlock: 1234,              // startAtBlock: the first block relevant to our application
    onlyIrreversible: false,         
    dbName: "db2",                   // name of the database
    mongoEndpoint: "uri",
  })
  const actionWatcher = new BaseActionWatcher(actionReader, actionHandler, 500)
  actionReader.initialize().then(()=>
  actionWatcher.watch())
})
```

Comment: Is that the only place in the script where you assign value to the `mS` variable?

Comment: We don't know how these two snippets are related in time or scope.

Comment: Please provide your question in more clear way. Add the whole code snippet.

Comment: Is this code in the same file? What does the entire script look like?

Comment: If you mean if I am letting ms = something only once then yes!

Comment: Yes all of it is in the same file.

Comment: @TabachiHarada The context of the code matters. We have to guess here how the code is interacting.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Are you using a library of some sort?

Comment: @Jonast92 yes I am using multiple modules

Comment: @TabachiHarada It would be helpful to tag the ones you're using in the question.

Comment: Not sure if I'm right so not posting as an answer but it may simply be a scope problem. The code executed within .then may need you to pass the mS variable as an argument so that it's reference-able.

Comment: as @Jonast92 this could be scope issue. Try wrapping a code in anonymous function or even a simple function and see if that works.